# Writing NSString As Char* Via Socket Not Working

Tags: objective-c, qt

I have two application Client (Written in Qt) and Server (Written in Objective-C) that communicate with each other. In one scenario I'm facing issue when server sends data via socket to Client. My code is as follows. I have some data that is pointed by **NSString* str** on the server that I'm writing to a socket as follows.

```
const char* socketData = [str UTF8String];
int len = strlen(socketData);
int writtenBytes = write(socket, socketData, len);
if(writtenBytes != len)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to write bytes");
}
```

In my case when server is writing to the socket **writtenBytes is equal to len**.

On my client I have connected a slot **OnSocketReadyRead()** connected to **QLocalSocket object SIGNAL**.

```
void onSocketReadyRead()
{
    QByteArray byteArray(myLocalSoket->readAll());
    QList<ByteArray> byteArrayList = byteArray.split("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < byteArrayList.count() ;i++)
    {
       qDebug() << "ByteArray Length: " << byteArrayList[i].length();
    }
    
}
```

Here the size I'm printing in the output window is not the same as **len** value in server code. length of bytes in server is 117 in client its showing 27.

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll), readAll() reads all *available* bytes on the socket. readyRead is emitted as soon as there are bytes available which can be only 1 or all or something in between. The other bytes are coming with the next readyRead() signal.

Comment: @chehrlic As mentioned length of data received and sent is different. So where is the issue, is the server not sending it or the client not reading properly?

Comment: And as I told you the readyRead() signal is emitted as soon as bytes are available. It does not mean that already all bytes received at this time. You have to wait for another readyRead() signal and combine the data.

Comment: Thanks @chehrilc but I just now learned that data is coming properly but the issue is another encoding at server side should happen but not happening but the data is being decoded at client thats y there is a mismatch of data.